# How to make a htacess RewriteRule with a url variable

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, web, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the url http://www.mywebsite.com/tutos/tutos.php?q=my-tuto/tuto-1.html to
http://www.mywebsite.com/tutos/tutos/my-tuto/tuto-1.html, how to do that with a .htaccess ?

I tried this, but it's don't working... :

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.mywebsite.com/tutos/([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/tutos/tutos.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that you have seems to be doing the *opposite* of what you say that you want. It's redirecting the non-query-string URL **to** the query-string URL. But if that's what you want, you need to remove the host and protocol from the regular expression. Only the URI (sans query string) is used to match against in a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^tutos/([^-]*)$ /tutos/tutos.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

But if you wanted it the other way around like you had asked:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&)q=([^&]+)(.*)
RewriteRule ^tutos/tutos.php$ /tutos/%2?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```